# How to get road data from HERE REST API

Tags: rest, here-api

I need to extract road geo coordinates (lattitude, longitude) and additional data such as lines number from HERE.com. I looked at Map Tile API - it returns only street labels. Besides that coordinates given in pixels.

Request example: https://2.base.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/streettile/newest/normal.day/16/39616/20487/256/png8?app_id={APP_ID}&app_code={APP_CODE}&metadata=metaonly&pois&mgen=2

Responce:

```
    {
        "metadata": {
            "street labels": [
                {
                    "name": "ulitsa Il'inka",
                    "font size": "13",
                    "vertices": [
                        252.12,
                        105.13,
                        273.23,
                        89.7,
                        283.94,
                        81.86,
                        292.44,
                        74.9,
                        295.3,
                        72.48,
                        301.29,
                        67.55,
                        311.49,
                        60
                    ]
                },
            ....
            "labels": [],
            "city center labels": [],
            "buildings": [],
            "transit stops": [],
            "POIs": []
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to get geo coordinates and additional data from HERE.com?

Answer (score 0):

Look at Platform Data Extension API
https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/introduction.html